# How do I keep track of multiple websites?

Tags: design, tracking, statistics

As an owner of multiple websites I sometimes find it difficult to remember when each site needs renewing. Another problem is that I have to log into every single site to check the site traffic statistics. Is there a centralized tool that I can use which will display all the websites in a table with their current stats, expiry dates etc? I noticed that people tend to use Excel, but this doesn't seem like a viable solution for my problem. I expect that the number of sites I own/maintain will continue to increase. I also design websites for others, most of which don't understand the concept of paying for hosting and domain names. If I was able to list other peoples sites which I have access to I would be able to notify them and arrange payment prior to it being required.

~Sam

Comment: A similar question was asked recently, "[Any solutions for managing all properties from one system?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17530/any-solutions-for-managing-all-properties-from-one-system)". This _might_ answer _some_ of your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Google Analytics track multiple sites (or 'website profiles' as they call it) on a single account.

Then the entry page of your GA account will list all your sites and a quick summary of the last day/week/month/year-s activity. You can also sort your sites by number of visitors, time on site etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked at [Google's Webmaster Central](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)? It has some site management stuff.

I use a calendar such as Outlook or Google calendar to track domain and hosting renewal dates.